# Copy to clipboard button on website not working

Tags: html, wordpress, clipboard

I used the code from this website:

http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/article.php/3458851

and modified the code to fit what I need:

```
<div align="center">
    <font size="5"><b><a href="https://secure.geobytes.com/IpLocator.htm?GetLocation&IpAddress=[show_ip]" target="_blank"><SPAN ID="copytext">[show_ip]</SPAN></a></b></font>
    <br />
    <TEXTAREA ID="holdtext" STYLE="display:none;"></TEXTAREA>
    <BUTTON onClick="ClipBoard();">Copy to Clipboard</BUTTON>
</div>
```

The code doesn't give any errors and it formats correctly but it's just not copying to the clipboard.

I am putting this in a TEXT WIDGET on Wordpress so I am limited on what I can do.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Thank you!

Comment: @ErocM that method will also only work on (old) versions of IE. A small subset of the Internet. You need to use a Flash snippet to get that working in most browsers. Just FYI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The site you copied from, in the link, also has the JS code for ClipBoard(); It's a little ways down the page. Looks like you missed it.

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">

function ClipBoard() 
{
holdtext.innerText = copytext.innerText;
Copied = holdtext.createTextRange();
Copied.execCommand("Copy");
}

</SCRIPT>
```

^^ From the site you linked.

Comment: Thank you I had not noticed that. I am new to Javascript and overlooked it.